# Woocommerce short description containing unwanted text

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, code-injection

From some time now, i noticed that my products short description has some text injected when the user is logged out, but i'm not that faimilar with WordPress's backend to figure out what's causing this.

The injected text seems like a list of words, that gets stumbled on every refresh, and to show you an example, it looks like this:

```
Download Best WordPress Themes Free DownloadDownload WordPress Themes FreeDownload WordPress Themes FreeDownload Nulled WordPress Themesfree online coursedownload coolpad firmwareDownload Nulled WordPress Themes
```

Also, this always gets added to the end of the short description. So for example if the short description is empty, and contains the trimmed description, it will be concatenated to the trimmed description.

Comment: did it happen at the beginning if not, please deactivate all your plugin and active one by one and check the changes, I hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Naaser ALi Karimi for the hint.
Looks like there was a hacked plugin installed on the application, which was causing the issue.

So if someone else bumps into this issue:
Don't install hacked plugins to WordPress, only ones that are from trusted sources, as it's very dangerous. Please buy the original product or don't use it, as you can get your website hacked, and some advertisement text is the least damage you could get from it.